# Convert a number in scientific notation to decimal format using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, notepad++

I am trying to to convert a number in scientific notation to decimal format (i.e. 3.44251E+12) so I found this XSLT function. But it given me an error saying that "Extra content at the end of the document".

```
<xsl:function name=“fn:remove-scientific-notation”> 
    <xsl:param name=“attr” /> 
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test=“matches($attr, ‘^\-?[\d\.,]*[Ee][+\-]*\d*$’)”> 
            <xsl:value-of 
                select=“format-number(number($attr), ‘#0.#############’)”> 
            </xsl:value-of> 
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:otherwise> 
            <xsl:value-of select=“$attr”></xsl:value-of> 
        </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:function>
```

Any thoughts? Any other ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor? If so, which one? And can you please post a minimal but complete stylesheet given the error? That snippet alone is not testable.

Comment: Can you also include the XML you're trying to convert? The error you're receiving is often caused by invalid XML.